# Double clicking to select all in R Studio

Tags: rstudio

I use RStudio Server and my behavior for double clicking has changed. In the past, when I double clicked on a word, it would highlight that work. But now, when I double click on the word it selects all of the content in my script.

It can be a problem when I double click and then press cmd + enter, since it runs the script.

Is that something that can be toggled?